# SPList OnQuickLaunch and QuickLaunchOptions not working

Tags: list, development

I am trying to hide the list from quick launch and it is not updating it. Here is the code

```
Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("Test", "Test", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
SPList list = web.Lists[listId];
list.OnQuickLaunch = false;  
list.Update();   //not updating
list.Fields.Add("Enabled", SPFieldType.Boolean, true);
list.Fields.Add("Action URL", SPFieldType.Text, true);
list.Update();  //adding the columns.
```

I am doing this on activating a feature but it is just not hiding the list from Quick Launch.

Comment: Did you update your web? web.update()

Comment: @Tanmay let me check if it works

Comment: @Tanmay it did not work.

Comment: Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.addtoquicklaunch%28v=office.14%29.aspx i don't have a dev machine right now so cant test anything

Comment: I want to remove a link and not add one

Comment: Oh! sorry missed that one.

Comment: Try to create the list with one of the overloaded methods that has parameter QuickLaunchOptions [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection_members.aspx)

Comment: @Naim even this did not work. it is cerating the list and adding columns but not hiding it from Quick Launch.

Comment: your code is fine. I just tested it and the created list is not shown in quick launch. After the list is created check in list settings -> Title,Description and Navigation, is it set to be shown in quick launch or not?

Comment: @Naim I figured it out. The Quick Launch was disabled and only Tree View was shown. Which created the confusion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good. Batter add your solution as an answer to this question.